# gfortran multiple definition of main

Tags: gcc, fortran, gfortran, gcc4

I'm having trouble with compiling a piece of code I have been given for my research. It consists of one component written in C++ and the other in FORTRAN. I think the problem is to do with my gcc version.

The first file for example is a C++ file (foo.ccp)

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

extern "C" {
  extern int MAIN__();
}

int main(){
    cout << "main in C++\n";
  return MAIN__();
}
```

The second is bar.f90:

```
program test
    implicit none
    print*, 'MAIN in FORTRAN'
end program test
```

I'm trying to compile it like so:

```
g++ -c foo.cpp
gfortran foo.o -lstdc++ bar.f90
```

It compiles fine with GCC-4.4.7 but fails with GCC-4.8.x with the error reading:

```
/tmp/cc5xIAFq.o: In function `main':
bar.f90:(.text+0x6d): multiple definition of `main'
foo.o:foo.cpp:(.text+0x0): first defined here
foo.o: In function `main':
foo.cpp:(.text+0x14): undefined reference to `MAIN__'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

I've read [here](https://gcc.gnu.org/ml/fortran/2009-08/msg00389.html) that there's a change in how gfortran handles naming of the 'main' and 'MAIN__' functions since version 4.5.x but I'm not sure how to fix my problem.

Any ideas as to what I'm missing? Thanks for your help!

Comment: You can only have 1 main. Where do you want it? In fortran or c?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have two `main` symbols:

```
int main(){
    cout << "main in C++\n";
  return MAIN__();
}
```

and

```
program test
    implicit none
    print*, 'MAIN in FORTRAN'
end program test
```

The main `program` is given the symbol `main`.  You cannot link these two programs together because the two `main` symbols conflict.  You also have the issue that since the Fortran `program` is given the `main` symbol and not `MAIN__` that symbol is undefined.  Your goal is to call Fortran from C++, you should do this:

```
#include <iostream>

extern "C" {
  int FortMain();
}

int main()
{
    std::cout << "main in C++\n";
    return FortMain();
}
```

and

```
function FortMain() bind(C,name="FortMain")
   use iso_c_binding
   implicit none
   integer(c_int) :: FortMain
   print *, "FortMain"
   FortMain = 0
end function FortMain
```

These will compile and link together and do what your code is attempting to do.  These make use of Fortran's `iso_c_binding` features to ensure the Fortran function is fully interoperable with C with proper case and no underscoring funny business.  The Fortran function also returns a value so matches the C prototype your have provided in your example.

Comment: yes, this worked. I replaced my FORTRAN program with a function as suggested. Thanks!