# NetBeans IDE Dev (Build 201804200002) "Build Failed"

Tags: gcc, netbeans, build, fortran

I am trying to learn Fortran using the NetBeans IDE   with the basic "Hello World" programming application. However, I keep getting "Build Failed". I don't know why? I have installed the MinGW. Then I configured the PATH in the Environment Variables. Finally, I installed NetBeans. This is what I programmed in NetBeans:

```
PRINT*, 'Hello World' 
END
```

The following is the error and the history that I get:

> cd 'C:\Users\ABCD\Documents\NetBeansProjects\CppApplication_1'
>
> C:\MinGW\msys\1.0\bin\make.exe -f Makefile CONF=Debug
>
> "/C/MinGW/msys/1.0/bin/make.exe" -f nbproject/Makefile-Debug.mk QMAKE=
>   SUBPROJECTS= .build-conf
>
> make.exe[1]: Entering directory 
>   `/c/Users/ABCD/Documents/NetBeansProjects/CppApplication_1'
>
> "/C/MinGW/msys/1.0/bin/make.exe"  -f nbproject/Makefile-Debug.mk
>   dist/Debug/MinGW-Windows/cppapplication_1.exe
>
> make.exe[2]: Entering directory
>   `/c/Users/ABCD/Documents/NetBeansProjects/CppApplication_1'
>
> mkdir -p build/Debug/MinGW-Windows
>
> gfortran   -c -g -o build/Debug/MinGW-Windows/testfortran.o
>   testfortran.f90
>
> mkdir -p dist/Debug/MinGW-Windows
>
> g++     -o dist/Debug/MinGW-Windows/cppapplication_1
>   build/Debug/MinGW-Windows/main.o
>   build/Debug/MinGW-Windows/testfortran.o
>
> build/Debug/MinGW-Windows/testfortran.o: In function `main':
>
> C:\Users\ABCD\Documents\NetBeansProjects\CppApplication_1/testfortran.f90:2:
>   multiple definition of `main'
>
> build/Debug/MinGW-Windows/main.o:C:\Users\ABCD\Documents\NetBeansProjects\CppApplication_1/main.cpp:21:
>   first defined here
>
> build/Debug/MinGW-Windows/testfortran.o: In function `MAIN__':
>
> C:\Users\ABCD\Documents\NetBeansProjects\CppApplication_1/testfortran.f90:1:
>   undefined reference to `_gfortran_st_write'
>
> C:\Users\ABCD\Documents\NetBeansProjects\CppApplication_1/testfortran.f90:1:
>   undefined reference to `_gfortran_transfer_character_write'
>
> C:\Users\ABCD\Documents\NetBeansProjects\CppApplication_1/testfortran.f90:1:
>   undefined reference to `_gfortran_st_write_done'
>
> build/Debug/MinGW-Windows/testfortran.o: In function `main':
>
> C:\Users\ABCD\Documents\NetBeansProjects\CppApplication_1/testfortran.f90:2:
>   undefined reference to `_gfortran_set_args'
>
> C:\Users\ABCD\Documents\NetBeansProjects\CppApplication_1/testfortran.f90:2:
>   undefined reference to `_gfortran_set_options'
>
> collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status
>
> make.exe[2]: *** [dist/Debug/MinGW-Windows/cppapplication_1.exe] Error
>   1
>
> make.exe[2]: Leaving directory 
>   `/c/Users/ABCD/Documents/NetBeansProjects/CppApplication_1'
>
> make.exe[1]: *** [.build-conf] Error 2
>
> make.exe[1]: Leaving directory
>   `/c/Users/ABCD/Documents/NetBeansProjects/CppApplication_1'
>
> make.exe": *** [.build-impl] Error 2
>
> BUILD FAILED (exit value 2, total time: 1s)

I am not understanding how do I fix it? I would appreciate any help as I am a beginner to the Fortran/C++ world.

Comment: Please pay attention to the formatting of the error message: it's very hard to see anything clearly as it is presented.  However, it looks like you are compiling/linking with g++ rather than gfortran?

Comment: Thanks, @francescalus . I edited my problem. Is that a better way to write? Also how do I fix that  it is compiling using g++ instead of gfortran?

Comment: Better, thanks.  Could also try as code block  rather than quote formatting, but this is much more readable.  As to using g++ to link (and the two object files), which is now more obvious, we'll need someone knowledgeable of the IDE.

Comment: @francescalus since you are so proficient in Fortran (I saw your profile :) ), I was wondering if you could  tell me how do I get fortran to start learning. The above way I did was followed this youtuber who showed how to install Fortran: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wGv2kGl8OV0

Comment: @Ska I'm wondering whether you have `gfortran` properly installed. It looks like you are running Windows, so what do you see if you open a `Command Prompt` window and enter **gfortran --version**?

Comment: Hi @skomisa. In the Command Prompt after I enter gfortran --version I get this message:GNU Fortran (MinGW.org GCC-6.3.0-1) 6.3.0
Copyright (C) 2016 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
This is free software; see the source for copying conditions.  There is NO
warranty; not even for MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.

Comment: Okay, Great @skomisa . Thank you. Looking forward to what's next.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I followed the video tutorial you linked to in your comment, and I got the same build errors. Two unrelated changes are needed to resolve them:

- To resolve the `multiple definition of 'main'` error, see the accepted answer to the Stack Overflow question [gfortran multiple definition of main](https://stackoverflow.com/q/33594960/2985643). Just copy and paste the source for the C++ and Fortran examples into your project files.

  Rebuild your project and the `multiple definition of 'main'` error should be gone.
- However, that does not fix the `undefined reference` errors. The solution for that is on the (old) [NetBeans web site](https://netbeans.org/projects/cnd/lists/users/archive/2011-11/message/129):

  > So, in the Linker window we when we add the reference to the Fortran
  >   library by bringing up the Libraries window one will notice an Add
  >   Options button on this page....here is where we put the -lgfortran
  >   option under Other Options. Presto, the C code will compile and
  >   doesn't complain about missing Fortran references.

The specific steps needed to fix the `undefined reference` errors are:

- In the **Projects** window select your project, right click and select **Properties** from the context menu to open the **Project Properties** window.
- Select **Build > Linker** from the **Categories** list.
- On the right side of the **Project Properties** window click the `...` button for **Libraries**.
- In the **Debug - Libraries** window click the **Add Option...** button.
- In the **Select Option** window:

  - Click the `Other Option` radio button.
  - Enter **-lgfortran** in the text field and press **OK**.
- Click OK to close **Debug - Libraries** window. You should now see the 
  **-lgfortran** option displayed in the **Project Properties** window:

  [image: linkerSettings]

Having made the changes described above the projects builds without errors:

```
cd 'D:\NB82\CppApplication_5'
C:\msys\1.0\bin\make.exe -f Makefile CONF=Debug clean
"/C/msys/1.0/bin/make.exe" -f nbproject/Makefile-Debug.mk QMAKE= SUBPROJECTS= .clean-conf
make.exe[1]: Entering directory `/d/NB82/CppApplication_5'
rm -f -r build/Debug
rm -f *.mod
make.exe[1]: Leaving directory `/d/NB82/CppApplication_5'

CLEAN SUCCESSFUL (total time: 558ms)
cd 'D:\NB82\CppApplication_5'
C:\msys\1.0\bin\make.exe -f Makefile CONF=Debug
"/C/msys/1.0/bin/make.exe" -f nbproject/Makefile-Debug.mk QMAKE= SUBPROJECTS= .build-conf
make.exe[1]: Entering directory `/d/NB82/CppApplication_5'
"/C/msys/1.0/bin/make.exe"  -f nbproject/Makefile-Debug.mk dist/Debug/MinGW-Windows/cppapplication_5.exe
make.exe[2]: Entering directory `/d/NB82/CppApplication_5'
mkdir -p build/Debug/MinGW-Windows
rm -f "build/Debug/MinGW-Windows/main.o.d"
g++    -c -g -MMD -MP -MF "build/Debug/MinGW-Windows/main.o.d" -o build/Debug/MinGW-Windows/main.o main.cpp
mkdir -p build/Debug/MinGW-Windows
gfortran   -c -g -Wall -o build/Debug/MinGW-Windows/newfortranFreeFormatFile.o newfortranFreeFormatFile.f90
mkdir -p dist/Debug/MinGW-Windows
g++     -o dist/Debug/MinGW-Windows/cppapplication_5 build/Debug/MinGW-Windows/main.o build/Debug/MinGW-Windows/newfortranFreeFormatFile.o -lgfortran
make.exe[2]: Leaving directory `/d/NB82/CppApplication_5'
make.exe[1]: Leaving directory `/d/NB82/CppApplication_5'

BUILD SUCCESSFUL (total time: 1s)
```

Running the Fortran project then produces the expected output:

```
main in C++
 FortMain

RUN SUCCESSFUL (total time: 2s)
```

Answer (score 0):

You have created a C++ project then a fortran file.
Your IDE created a main in c++ for you. I guess it havent in the tutorial you have seen.
If i have seen it right then the answer is simple:

Just right click and delete this main.c and you are good :-)